# AngularJS performing math

Tags: angular, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this scope function where it has a cost and a formatted value in data. That cost and formatted value are coming from an API. The formatted value can be in a different currency not limited to Euro or USD, but globally, Baht, PHP, CHF, etc.

How do I perform math operations like adding using the `formattedValue` data, instead of using the value data?

I want to retain the symbol or format of whatever currency I received as a response from the API. The sum will be displayed in the DOM with the currency symbol and format.

```
$scope.performMath = () => { 
    const prices = [
        {
          price: {
            formattedValue: "€ 200,00",
            value: "200"
          }
        },
        {
          price: {
            formattedValue: "€ 400,00",
            value: "400"
          }
        },
        {
          price: {
            formattedValue: "€ 200,00",
            value: "500"
          }
        }];
    const sumPrices = (prices) => prices.reduce((value, item) => value + (parseFloat(item.price.value) || 0), 0);
    $scope.totalItemPrice = sumPrices(prices).toFixed(2);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this may not be a direct solution to your problem, but if you could include `currency` code (like `USD`, `EUR`, etc.) and `locale` value (like `en-us`, `en-gb`), then there is a built-in Javascript object [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) which has a method [Intl.NumberFormat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) to convert a number to the desired currency format.

Here's an example:

```js
let num = 1234567.89; // This would be the result of your reducer method

// --- Extract this method and make it as a globally accessible utility, if you want
const formatNumber = (num, locale, curr) => {
  const formatOptions = {
    style: "currency",
    currency: curr
  };

  return Intl.NumberFormat(locale, formatOptions).format(num);
}

console.log(formatNumber(1234567.89, "en-gb", "EUR"))
// Output: €1,234,567.89

// NOTE: Both en-gb and en-GB works the same (case-insensitive)
```

Instead of sending over a pre-formatted currency string might hinder the extensibility of your app. Rather (if possible) try sending the currency code and locale via the existing API might of greater help.

Here are two stack-overflow links which you might find useful:

- [How to format numbers as currency strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-strings)
- [Is there a way to reverse the formatting by Intl NumberForat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255843/is-there-a-way-to-reverse-the-formatting-by-intl-numberformat-in-javascript)

Comment: Hey @stellainlucem, I know it's been around 6 months now. Did it solve your problem? Feedback always helps. Cheers!