# Jquery Adding tax to price with commas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am having trouble calculating with commas in my price what would be de best solution to solve this?

I am console log the right price and want to get the tax.

example console log: "€1.652,89"

```js
                $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
                    var price = $('.yith_wcp_group_final_total').text();
                    
                    
                    console.log(price);
                    var tax = 21
                    var total = (price * tax) / 100;
                    $('#B_subtotal').html(total);
                    console.log(total);
                });
```

//EDIT

```js
            $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
                  var price = $('.yith_wcp_group_final_total').text();
                    price = Number(price.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g,""));
                    console.log(price)
                    var tax = 21
                    var total = price * (100 + tax) / 100;
                    var roundup = total.toFixed(2);
                    $('#B_subtotal').html(roundup);
                    console.log(total);
                    console.log(roundup);
                
            });
```

So i get 1.900,83
and after the calculation i get 2.3000043

How could I get the comma and dots back on the right place?

Comment: You should include jQuery in your page...

Comment: `€1.652,89` must be converted to float `1652.89` before you can make any computation

Comment: also, what you call `total` is actually the tax amount. Total would be `price * (100 + tax) / 100`

Comment: Thank you, I now have the right total but i get this back
price = 1.652,89
price * (100 + tax) / 100 gets back 2.2499949999999997
this needs to be 2.250,00 

what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: total should be `1999.9969`, you can round it up to `2000,00` using `toFixed(2)`

Comment: @GrafiCode I get back 2.00

Comment: I'll try and elaborate an answer, what's your locale? `de-DE`?

Comment: @GrafiCode Not really understand what you mean But i gues nl-NL

Comment: @Bent I posted my answer, please check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to convert "€1.652,89" from "currency" to float. In this example I used the `parseLocaleNumber` function (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29273131/5334486).

This gives you float `1652.89` which can be correctly used to compute taxes and total.

You can then format `total` back to currency using `Intl.NumberFormat()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

```js
let price = "€1.652,89"

const taxPercent = 21

// REMOVE THE EURO SYMBOL FROM PRICE
price = price.substring(1)

// CONVERT LOCALIZED NUMBER TO FLOAT
const priceAsNumber = parseLocaleNumber(price, 'nl')
console.log(priceAsNumber) // 1652.89

// GET TAXES
const taxAmount = priceAsNumber * taxPercent / 100
console.log(taxAmount) // 347.1069

// GET TOTAL
const total = priceAsNumber + taxAmount
console.log(total) // 1999.9969

// FORMAT TOTAL TO CURRENCY
const totalRounded = new Intl.NumberFormat('nl-NL', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(total)

console.log(totalRounded) // "€ 2.000,00"


//
// HELPER FUNCTION
//
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/29273131/5334486
//
function parseLocaleNumber(stringNumber, locale) {
    var thousandSeparator = Intl.NumberFormat(locale).format(11111).replace(/\p{Number}/gu, '');
    var decimalSeparator = Intl.NumberFormat(locale).format(1.1).replace(/\p{Number}/gu, '');

    return parseFloat(stringNumber
        .replace(new RegExp('\\' + thousandSeparator, 'g'), '')
        .replace(new RegExp('\\' + decimalSeparator), '.')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting values in a string. Just convert the string into a float as we have a decimal point and apply regex as we have a currency sign in it. Regex will check the value and we will get the value in float which can be used with tax multiplication.

```js
  var price = $('.yith_wcp_group_final_total').text();
  price = Number(price.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g,""));
  console.log(price)
  var tax = 21
  var total = (price * tax) / 100;
  $('#B_subtotal').html(total);

  total = price + total
  console.log(total.toLocaleString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This would need to be `/[^0-9\,-]+/` as example is 1.652,89

Comment: Is it possible to put the comma back after the calculation? so i get a normal price?

Comment: @Bent you can assign it in temp variable like var temp = $('.yith_wcp_group_final_total').text() and after the calculation you can reassign the value to the DOM, BTW value is not changing for $('.yith_wcp_group_final_total').text()

Comment: could you maybe show me how this could be done?

Comment: with tax price?

Comment: yes so lets say the price is 1.652,89 without tax and I want to add 21% back
price * (100 + tax) / 100

I get back  2.2499949999999997
how can I get this to 2.250,00

Comment: @Bent actually you get back `1999.9969`

Comment: @GrafiCode not if I added you code "price * (100 + tax) / 100 "

Comment: @Bent `1652.89 * 121 / 100` equals `1999.9969`

Comment: @Bent if this answer is helpful kindly approve it as an answer thanks

Comment: @GrafiCode my bad had the wrong number.... sorry.

But If i have 1.859,50 i get back 2.2499949999999997 how can I round this up to 2.250,00 en put the comma back?